# Large .tif image dataset - How do I convert it to a usable dataset for a CNN using Tensorflow with labels in a separate CSV? Python 3

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have been trying to find a way to convert my 270,000 .tif images and their corresponding labels into a usable Tensorflow dataset for a few days now and I have decided to post here for help.

What I have currently done is just taken a subset of the images and converted them to numpy arrays and then put them into a list. I also did this with the labels. So I now have a pandas dataframe that has two columns; id (the images file name) and the label (a 1 or a 0) and a list of numpy arrays. Below is the code that I use to do that.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import re


path = "./training_images/*"

img_names = []
img_arr_list = []
for file in glob.glob(path):
    img = Image.open(file)
    img_arr = np.asarray(img).astype("float32")
    img_arr_list.append(img_arr)
    name = re.split(' |/|\\\\' , file)
    name = name[2][:-4]
    img_names.append(name)

labels = pd.read_csv("train_labels.csv")

# Convert list of file names to a pandas dataframe and change the 0 field to "id" to match the field
# name in labels
name_df = pd.DataFrame(img_names)
name_df = name_df.rename(columns={0:"id"})

# inner join to get only the images names and their labels that exist in the image subset
labels_df = pd.merge(name_df,labels,on='id',how='inner')
```

From here, I have tried to convert my list of numpy arrays as well is it's corresponding labels into a Tensorflow dataset that I can then preprocess and then feed into a CNN that I will later create. When I execute the below code.....

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_arr_list, labels_df))
```

.... I get this error..

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

I believe I am doing this incorrectly and need to instead be doing something where I iterate over my list of numpy arrays and my labels_df to create a tensor during each loop in the for loop and then append them to a Tensorflow dataset. Below is some pseudo-code that I have thought of using.

```
for row in [0,len(img_arr_list)]:
    tensor = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((img_arr_list[row], labels_df.iloc[row]))
    <append tensor to tensorflow dataset>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I am also open to using a pytorch-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Load data like in this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/loading-custom-image-dataset-for-deep-learning-models-part-1-d64fa7aaeca6):

```
def create_dataset(img_folder):
   
    img_data_array=[]
    class_name=[]
   
    for dir1 in os.listdir(img_folder):
        for file in os.listdir(os.path.join(img_folder, dir1)):
       
            image_path= os.path.join(img_folder, dir1,  file)
            image= cv2.imread( image_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            image=cv2.resize(image, (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
            image=np.array(image)
            image = image.astype('float32')
            image /= 255 
            img_data_array.append(image)
            class_name.append(dir1)
    return img_data_array, class_name
```

Comment: Thanks @iamXXVI I tried that solution in my first for loop for setting the img_arr variable, but maybe I'm implementing it incorrectly? Should I be converting my img_arr_list to a bumpy array? With that, I would have a numpy array of numpy arrays. I don't know how that would work for feeding it into a model.

Comment: oh I just noticed that you are using img_arr_list (numpy array) and labels_df (pandas DataFrame). That is why it is not working mostly. I have edited my answer. Try loading data like that.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had gone to bed. It was quite late here. I will test this out on my lunch break and get back to you. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I am unsure of how to correctly implement your code. I have written the code to invoke the function as seen here

img_data, class_name =create_dataset('./training_images/')

but this does not also include my CSV file for the labels. It also returns an error saying that I have an invalid file path as the create_dataset function is attempting to use './training_images\\<image_filename>.tif instead of the actual folder.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. What is happening now is that I have images that are all of "training_images" class instead of a 1 or 0. I will have to figure this out. Thank you for the thoughts.